# Селектор не переключает картинку

Tags: android, xml

**Селектор:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/sound_on" android:state_selected="true"></item>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/sound_off"></item>

</selector>
```

Добавил в `ImageView`. Хочу чтобы при нажатии картинка сменилась, после повторного нажатия картинка опять сменилась и т.д.

Как вы поступаете в таком случае? Используете селекторы или есть что-то лучше в Андроид?

Comment: Вы CheckBox что ли переизобрести пытаетесь?)

Comment: @xkor, а что разве у CheckBox есть параметр src? как у Image?

Comment: нет, но у него есть атрибуты background и button

Comment: Да и ImageView в принципе подойдет, просто меняйте ей стэйт на нужный при клике.

Comment: @xkor, Это как эй стет? подробнее можно?

Comment: ну если вы задали в селекторе `android:state_selected="true"` то значит надо для отображения этого изображения установить imageView в выделенное состояние: `imageView.setSelected(true)`

Comment: @xkor, А почему в xml ImageVIew нет такого параметра selected? я хотел через xml true установить

Comment: потому что это не логично

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42612/discussion-between-xtigrx-and-xkor).

Comment: @xkor, checkBox самое то. спс